# Scala class constructor's default argument naming

Tags: scala, reflection

I need to instantiate Scala class using reflection.

I want to use class default constructor which has arguments with default values, so I need to get these default values.

Default values in Scala are just methods in JVM, so I need to get all class methods and call only those are returns default values.

The question: I see that there are two different naming conventions for methods which returns default arg values - "**apply$default$X**" and "**$lessinit$greater$default$X**" (*where X is a number of position of particular argument*).
What is the difference between these two?
Maybe it depends on Scala version or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a case class

```
case class Foo(bar: Int)
```

then this creates both a normal class and a companion object:

```
class Foo(bar: Int) { // def toString, hashCode, equals 
}
object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Int) = new Foo(bar)
  // def unapply
}
```

Of course, if you have default parameter values, both the constructor and the `apply` method have to use those default values; any other behavior would be quite surprising.

So the constructor's default values are returned by `$lessinit$greater$default$X` methods (because the constructor's name is `<init>`). `apply$default$X` are the default values for the `apply` method.

For non-case classes you should only see `$lessinit$greater$default$X`, unless you define the `apply` method yourself.

Comment: But additional question: why there are two different default value methods for both apply() and <init>?

If I declare class Foo(bar: Int = 0) than companion object should also use this particular value and two methods is just a boilerplate.

Comment: I assume that's just to avoid making this a special case. When inserting the default value method calls, the compiler currently only needs to know the method name and signature.